# Grab unique data from repeating record

Tags: mysql

I've got a procedural question that is likely going to expose how burnt out I am. I have 3 tables, users, projects and project_users. projects is joined with project_user to allow users to share projects.

I'd like to let, say, Bob see all of his projects and who he is sharing them with. In the example below Bob's sharing his 1 project with everyone. In his dashboard I'd like to show him "Bob's 1 Project" with everyone it's shared with. This is being managed in a while loop because Bob really has dozens of projects he's sharing with dozen's of people. The problem is, how can I show 1 project with everyone it's shared_with instead of showing the same project over and over each time there's a new shared_with value?

```
id | users              | | id | projects          | | id | owner_id | shared_with | project_id | role
---+--------------------    ---+-------------------    ---+----------+-------------+------------+------
1  | bob@here.com       | | 1  | Bob's 1 Project   | | 1  | 1        | NULL        | 1          | 1
2  | tom@there.com      | | 2  | Tom's             | | 2  | 1        | 4           | 1          | 2
3  | jan@red.com        | | 3  | Jan's             | | 3  | 1        | 2           | 1          | 2          
4  | joe@somewhere.com  | | 4  | Joe's Project     | | 4  | 1        | 3           | 1          | 2
5  | fred@where.com     | | 5  | Fred's Project    | | 5  | 1        | 5           | 1          | 2
```

Comment: You need something like this. https://www.tarynpivots.com/post/how-to-rotate-rows-into-columns-in-mysql/ Google for "convert rows to columns"

Comment: I am now calling a function within the while loop that lists all those with whom the project is shared. This seems wildly inefficient and may melt the Internet. It works, however.